# How do I change style.display from none to inline when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I want to display `id="text"` when the button is clicked. So I tried this:

```
    <form name="i_choose_form" action="" method="post">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="I am not sure, show me other choices..." onclick = "showText()"></br>
    </form>

    <span id ="text" style="display:none">First make your choice then you can see all other choices</span>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

function showText() { document.getElementById("text").style.display="inline"; }

</script>
```

But this does not work as expected and text is not displayed. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/dPhUQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is shown, but you are submitting the page. Change your input to type='button' instead of 'submit'

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="I am not sure, show me other choices..." onclick = "showText()"></br>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also changed the jfiddle setup by Pointy's answer

Answer (score 1):

You are not cancelling the click event for the submit button so the page will submit the form.

```
onclick = "showText(); return false;"
```

You should really look at adding the events [unobtrusively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

```
<input type="submit" id="showMore" class="button" value="I am not sure, show me other choices..." onclick = "showText()">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showText() { 
        document.getElementById("text").style.display="inline";
    }
    document.getElementById("showMore").click = showText;
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems that it is still refreshing the page http://jsfiddle.net/dPhUQ/1/

Comment: You haven't copied the example correctly. `onclick = "showText()" return false;` should be `onclick = "showText(); return false;"`

Comment: sorry, now it works. Thanks. Both changing "submit" to "button" and this version works. Is there a reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: submit posts back the form, button does not.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you've got jsfiddle set up.  On the left is a pull-down to choose how the site incorporates your JavaScript into the result page.  Set it to "no wrap (head)" and it'll work. Well, it won't work, actually, but it'll call your function.

The next problem you'll have is that your "submit" button will submit the form immediately after your handler runs.  To prevent that, you'll need to stop event propagation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your FORM is interfering with your desired results, try this instead:

```
<div onclick = "showText()">Click me</div>
```